# How to Group or nest to a subset of the data in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, tidyverse

1. **Issue**: How to keep the variation of `sizes` in `geom_point()` based on data subset to respective `month` only.
2. I am new in R and have created a `facet plot` based on `months` for **Top  5 countries**  with `confirmed` covid cases count in each month. Right now the size is varying based on `Cases_count` across the `months` but would like to restrict it to based on respective month only.

[image]

3. **Below is the code for same**

```
df_stack %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(Date, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(Cases_type == "Confirmed") %>% 
  group_by(month, Country.Region) %>% 
  summarise(Cases_count = sum(Cases_count, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  top_n(n = 5, wt = Cases_count) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  
  # Adding continents to data
  left_join(y = df_stack %>% 
              select(Country.Region, continent) %>% 
              unique(),
            by = "Country.Region") %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = continent, y = Country.Region)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, aes(size = Cases_count, color = as.factor(continent)), fill = "white", stroke = 3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~month) +
  labs(title = "Top 5 confirmed cases Countries across the year")
```

4. **Code to view data**:

```
df_stack %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(Date, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(Cases_type == "Confirmed") %>% 
  group_by(month, Country.Region) %>% 
  summarise(Cases_count = sum(Cases_count, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  top_n(n = 5, wt = Cases_count) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  
  # Adding continents to data
  left_join(y = df_stack %>% 
              select(Country.Region, continent) %>% 
              unique(),
            by = "Country.Region")

######## output ########

A tibble: 60 x 4
   month Country.Region   Cases_count continent
   <ord> <chr>                  <dbl> <fct>    
 1 Jan   China                  38008 Asia     
 2 Jan   Japan                     56 Asia     
 3 Jan   Singapore                 53 Asia     
 4 Jan   Taiwan*                   52 Asia     
 5 Jan   Thailand                  94 Asia     
 6 Feb   China                1633361 Asia     
 7 Feb   Diamond Princess       10076 Unknown  
 8 Feb   Italy                   3966 Europe   
 9 Feb   Japan                   2418 Asia     
10 Feb   Korea, South           12128 Asia     
# ... with 50 more rows
```

5. **Desired output / Issue**: I would like to restrict the `size` variation of `geom_point()` based on Cases_count grouped to each `month` only and **not** on the whole dataframe `Cases_count`.
6. **Attempt**

I have tried with `group_by(month)` as shown in below code but that didn't help either.

```
df_stack %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(Date, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(Cases_type == "Confirmed") %>% 
  group_by(month, Country.Region) %>% 
  summarise(Cases_count = sum(Cases_count, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  top_n(n = 5, wt = Cases_count) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%

  # Adding continents to data  
  left_join(y = df_stack %>% 
              select(Country.Region, continent) %>% 
              unique(),
            by = "Country.Region") %>% 
  
  # Grouping by month to keep geom_point size variation to month only
  group_by(as.factor(month)) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(x = continent, y = Country.Region)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, aes(size = Cases_count, color = as.factor(continent)), fill = "white", stroke = 3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~month) +
  labs(title = "Top 5 confirmed cases Countries across the year")
```

[image]

**Update**: link of **code** used to recreate `df_stack` dataframe from scratch

https://github.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/blob/main/df_stack_for_stackoverflow.txt

Data is fetched from various covid r libraries used in the code.

Comment: Hi ViSa, it will be challenging to answer this question without working data. If you downloaded this data from a GitHub repo, perhaps you could provide code to reproduce `df_stack`?

Comment: Hi @IanCampbell, I have updated the code in Gihub repo @: https://github.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/blob/main/df_stack_for_stackoverflow.txt. Since I am using r library for downloading data so you should be able to recreate df_stack with this. Please note that I have used the github for first time so not sure if I did that correctly or not. Let me know if you are not able to access the code. thanks !

Comment: Your code to reproduce `df_stack` is too complicated. Next time, please upload a `.csv` file containing the data to GitHub and provide a `read.csv(url="<url here>")` call in your question as I demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @IanCampbell, this looks much better way to proceed. I should have thought of this. Then I wouldn't have to sort all relevant code chunks to share and you didn't need to rerun all the messy code as well. Thanks for showing me, will follow this approach from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the simplest way is to regroup by `month` and then use `mutate` to create a new variable specifically to determine the size. Then set the `ggplot` `size =`  aesthetic to the new variable.

Note also that you can simply save the continent in the call to `summarise`, no need to `left_join`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_stack <- read.csv(url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ianmcampbell/RandomStackOverflow/main/df_stack.csv"))
df_stack %>% 
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(Date, label = TRUE, abbr = TRUE)) %>%
  filter(Cases_type == "Confirmed") %>% 
  group_by(month, Country.Region) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(Cases_count = sum(Cases_count, na.rm = TRUE),
            continent = first(continent)) %>% 
  top_n(n = 5, wt = Cases_count) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(Cases_size = Cases_count / sum(Cases_count)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = continent, y = Country.Region)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, aes(size = Cases_size, color = as.factor(continent)), fill = "white", stroke = 3) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        legend.position = "none") +
  facet_wrap(~month) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  labs(title = "Countries with the greatest number of confirmed cases by month")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ian for putting in so much efforts into this to help me with the solution. This worked perfectly as I wanted and it was really a smart way of overcoming this issue. And thanks for showing me `summarise` `(- left_join)`, `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` approach as well. This was all new for me. Got to learn alot from you in this SO post.